# Hive Multiple Map rows to one map row

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a below table from which I need to derive distinct account_id with all rows in the remaining 2 columns as map<fl_group_id,fl_group_value>.Please guide me to get this fixed, thanks

Input

```
|  account_id    | fl_group_id          | fl_group_value          |
+----------------+----------------------+-------------------------+
| 1152956260987  | 10                   | 983                     |
| 1152956260987  | 12                   | 2144                    |
| 1152956260987  | 1                    | 82                      |
```

Expected output

```
|  account_id    | account_flg
+----------------+----------------------
| 1152956260987  | {"10":"983","12":"2144","1":"82"}
```

I have tried the below Query in the hive

`create table wf_test2 as select account_id, map(fl_group_id,fl_group_value) as account_flags from wf_test ;`

`select a.account_id,collect_set(a.account_flags)as account_flags from wf_test2 a where a.account_id='1152956260987' group by a.account_id ;`

But I am getting output as `array<map<string,string>>` instead of `map<string,string>`

```
| 1152956260987  | [{"10":"983"},{"12":"2144"},{"1":"82"}] |
```

Show Create table wf_test2

```
CREATE TABLE `wf_test2`(                           
   `account_id` string,                             
   `account_flags` map<string,string>)              
 ROW FORMAT SERDE                                   
   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'      
 STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                              
   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'  
 OUTPUTFORMAT                                       
   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat' 
 LOCATION                                           
   'hdfs://hive/wf_test2'           
 TBLPROPERTIES (                                    
   'bucketing_version'='2',                         
   'transactional'='true',                          
   'transactional_properties'='default',            
   'transient_lastDdlTime'='1596648078')
```

Comment: can you share the `wf_test2` show create table since could not run `select a.account_id,collect_set(a.account_flags)as account_flags from wf_test a where a.account_id='1152956260987' group by a.account_id ; `  query

Comment: @smart_coder  I have now added "create table DDL" in the question

Comment: You can use Klout Brickhouse UDFs to do this with their custom `collect` function.
Something like `SELECT account_id,collect(id,value) FROM table GROUPING BY account_id`.

Answer (score 0):

the below approach might be helpful as per @Hitobat comments in hive shell, using brickhouse-0.6.0.jar Maven repo - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.klout/brickhouse

```
create table wf_test2 (account_id string, account_flags map<string,string>) row format delimited  fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' LOCATION '/stackoverflow/data/hive/dwh/wf_test2' stored as textfile;

insert overwrite table wf_test values ("1152956260987","10","983"),("1152956260987","12","2144"),("1152956260987","1","82");

select * from wf_test;

-- 1152956260987    10  983
-- 1152956260987    12  2144
-- 1152956260987    1   82

add jar file:///home/sathya/Downloads/brickhouse-0.6.0.jar;

create temporary function collect as 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF';

select account_id, collect(fl_group_id,fl_group_value) from wf_test group by account_id;

--- 1152956260987   {"10":"983","1":"82","12":"2144"}

create table wf_test2 (account_id string, account_flags map<string,string>) row format delimited  fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' stored as textfile;

insert overwrite table wf_test2 select account_id, collect(fl_group_id,fl_group_value) from wf_test group by account_id;

select * from wf_test2;

-- 1152956260987    {"10":"983","1":"82","12":"2144"}
```